# Check if user ever purchased consumable item, + way of consuming items

Tags: java, android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have two questions about in-app purchases managed by google play.

1) How do I know if user ever purchased consumable from my app? It's not hard to change a flag in SharedPreferences when he purchase it (or when I consume it right after purchase), but when user uninstall app a install it again, flag is lost and I don't know if he ever purchased something or not.

2) Right way of using consumables - consumable have to be usable only for current installed session of app right? So it's ok when user purchase consumable, uninstall app, reinstall it and he don't have it anymore?

I've been searching in docs but these things are missing.

Thanks for reply.